# what is the usage of PerformanceCounter class in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I worked on enterprise library performance that I met this class. Now what is the usage of `PerformanceCounter` class?

Comment: Have you looked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) ? it relates to NT performance counters. You can add your own counters, etc.

Comment: Could you clarify, "what is the usage" - that term could mean "how do you use X", "is X widely used", etc - is the documentation not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

> Different performance counter types are available, covering different performance interests. They range from counts to those which calculate averages. Some of the performance counter types are for special situations only, but the following list contains the most common types you will normally use - and this article is covering:
>
> **NumberOfItems32** - a counter that counts the number of items. You can use it to calculate how often an operation was performed or to count the total number of items you processed.
>
> **RateOfCountsPerSecond32** - a counter that tracks down the number of items or operations per second.
>
> **AverageTimer32** - a counter that measures the average time required to perform an operation. The counter is calculated by the ratio of the total time elapsed and the number of items completed during that time. This comes along with ...
>
> **AverageBase** - the base counter for AverageTimer32 which counts the number of items completed during the elapsed time.
>
> You will find the performance counter types in the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterType` enumeration. Some of the counters found in that enumeration end with "Base" which indicates them as supporting counters for other counters which perform calculations (such as AverageTimer32). Whenever you set up a counter that performs calculations, you'll need to set up a supporting "Base" - counter.

Taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx)